# Where can I find a reference to the format of the comment field (field 5) of the /etc/passwd file?

Tags: files, users, password

In the `/etc/passwd` file on my system, the "comment" field, field 5, is inconsistent in its contents.  I thought that I could extract it to get the full name of the user.

```
fullname=`awk -F: '$1 == name {print $5}' name=$LOGNAME /etc/passwd`
```

However this returns with `$fullname` containing a name with 0, 3, or 4 commas following.  Exploring the man page (`man 5 passwd`) provides no details of this field other than describing it as "user name or comment field."

Perhaps there is additional information that is stored along with the user name?

Comment: It is simply a comment field - e.g. this is an example: `dbus:x:81:81:System message bus:/:/bin/false`. I think the comments associated to a user account when created with `useradd` or `adduser` is put here. But I mean, who does that?

Comment: Then it must be my distro which has decided that commas belong there.

Comment: I have them too. It probably signifies that no comment is associated with the user.

Comment: as mentioned in [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/186967/what-does-mean-in-the-5-column-in-etc-passwd-file/187027/), there is the finger(1) utility to retrieve information of these fields.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This field is often formatted as a [GECOS field](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gecos_field), which typically has 4 comma-separated fields for extra information in addition to the user's name, such as phone number, building number, etc.

In all cases I have seen, if the field has a comma, the name is what is before the comma. But I can imagine cases where this is not the case (a name of "Foo Bar, Jr" would break, for instance).

Comment: Excellent resource!  Thank you!  It's always a good feeling when one emerges from the darkness of ignorance.  Your answer has helped me do this.  :)

Comment: According to the man page for [`chfn`](http://linux265.rwc.uc.edu/cgi-bin/htmlman?command=chfn&flag=HTML), "_The only restriction placed on the contents of the fields is that no control characters may be present, nor any of comma, colon, or equal sign._"

Comment: Interestingly, the University of Cincinnati's [browsable man pages](http://linux265.rwc.uc.edu/htmlman.html) is where I discovered that; but I don't see the same caveat in other man page sources... ??

Comment: That's because you were looking at the manual pages from Thorsten Kukuk's pwdutils package, not the manual pages from other packages (and indeed non-Linux operating systems) providing that command.