# How do you grab someone's first name from /etc/passwd using grep and whoami?

Tags: bash, shell-script

How do you grab someone's first name from `/etc/passwd` using `grep` and `whoami`?

Comment: You don't. `whoami` doesn't refer to _someone else_

Comment: consider editing your title and change *whomi* to `whoami`

Comment: How do you even know there are first names in `/etc/passwd`? There certainly aren't on my system.

Comment: As pointed out at https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/28568/5132 , where the "W" in _How do I do X with W?_ was `awk`, the tool for this is `finger`.

Comment: Show us what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what you mean by `first name` but if you want to get user's real first name and last name stored in 5th field you can do:

```
grep "^$(whoami):" /etc/passwd | cut -d: -f5
```

And if you really want only the first name:

```
grep "^$(whoami):" /etc/passwd | cut -d: -f5 | cut -d' ' -f1
```

Comment: For me, field 5 has commas to delimit the various GECOS fields (`First Last,,,,`), so the first command includes the trailing commas.  If I want only the full name, then I'd do `grep "$(whoami)" /etc/passwd | cut -d: -f5 | cut -D, -f1`.

Answer (score 1):

```
getent passwd $(whoami) | cut -d: -f5 | cut -d, -f1 | cut '-d ' -f1
```

`getent passwd` tends be the better way to get user information compared to `grep [pattern] /etc/passwd`, since getent also supports LDAP or NIS if the system is configured to use that for user management.

`cut -d: -f5` takes the 5th field from the colon-separated password entry. That field is traditionally called gecos and contains the users full name, but also other things.

`cut -d, -f1` then takes the first sub-field of the comma-separated gecos field: the users full name.

`cut '-d ' -f1` takes the first word of the name, which should be the users first name.

Note that the last step really only takes the first word of the name, which may not actually be the right thing to do. More on that can be found in the popular essay ["Falsehoods Programmers Believe About Names" by Patrick McKenzie.](https://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/)